# Как нарисовать координатную сетку на Tpanel в firemonkey?

Tags: delphi, pascal, radstudio, firemonkey

Создала класс на основе Tpanel. Переопределила процедуру Paint. 
procedure   Paint; override;
Создаю динамически свою панель и кладу на Scrollbox. Ничего не рисуется.

```
procedure Tfield.Paint;
var a,b,c : integer;
    i,j : integer;
    PixelRegion: TRectF;
    PixelPos: TPointF;
begin
 // inherited paint;
   self.Canvas.Fill.Color:=  TAlphaColors.Crimson;
   self.Canvas.FillEllipse(rect(1,1,10,10),self.AbsoluteOpacity);
   self.Canvas.FillEllipse(rect(round(self.Width-9),round(self.Height-9),round(self.Width), round(self.Height)),self.AbsoluteOpacity);
   self.Canvas.FillEllipse(rect(round(self.Width-9),1,round(self.Width), 9),self.AbsoluteOpacity);
   self.Canvas.FillEllipse(rect(1,round(self.Height-9),10, round(self.Height)),self.AbsoluteOpacity);

end;
```

Почему не происходит перерисовка? Когда я работаю с классом на основе Timage все прекрасно работает. Объясните пожалуйста как правильно рисовать на канве Tpanel в Firemonkey.

Comment: я конечно уже весьма далек от мира делфи и фмх, но нельзя ли создать кисть рисующую сетку и применить ее к панели? в D2D, например,  так делается легко

Comment: Поставьте точку останова и проверьте, исполняется ли ваш код. Мне кажется, что проблема в прозрачности, а не в переопределении.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не задал параметры линий которыми должно происходить рисование.